# I want to get each visitor count those who are visiting my website and want to display in index page

Tags: php

I want to get each visitor count  those who are visiting my website and store to database.correct me.

I have used:

```
$client  = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

I don't understand which one i have to use. beacuse  i have hosted in server . I have checked both.

```
echo $client; //no output
echo $remote; //163.53.204.24
```

Comment: Use Google Analytics. Both `$_SERVER` variables do not "count" visitor. It may show the visitor's IP only.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i have seen the link http://www.google.co.in/analytics using that shall I count the user and i want to point in my website 200,201 user are seeing the websit

Comment: by this time 200 people are visited my site correct me if i am wrong

Comment: if i give in cmd prompt ipconfig: it is showing:192.168.1.101 if some one is seeing by url is using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; shall i get the userip or my hosted server ip

Comment: How can I know ? Google Analytics (GA) require login. p.s. GA has realtime statistics, if configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the user's IP:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Table

```
create table visitors (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  ip varchar(32) not null,
  visits int not null default 0,
  primary key(id)
)engine=innodb;
```

Code

```
$visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$db = mysql_connect('','','');

$query = 
    mysql_query('select * from visitors where ip = \''.$visitor.'\';');

if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
    mysql_query('insert into visitors (ip) values (\''.$visitor.'\');');
} else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
    $id = $row[0]['id'];
    $visits = $row[0]['visits'];
    ++$visits;

    mysql_query('update visitors set visits = ' . $visits . ' where id = ' . $id);
}

mysql_close($db);
```

I haven't tested this, but, it should be pretty close.

Comment: thanks lot here i have basic doubt  if some one is seeing by my url. by using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; shall i get the client userip address or client server ip address,

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR will give you the user's IP who visited your website, so, that is the best thing to use for unique identification (besides somebody logging in).

Comment: once again thanks lot my final query what does this function do $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']; because i executed on my server it does not echo any values